# Karma + Sinon fake timer = global leak errors?

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, sinon, karma-runner

I'm trying to use Sinon's fake timers in some of my unit tests (Karma runner with Mocha).  As soon as I add `clock = sinon.useFakeTimers();` to my `setup()` function, I get the following error:

```
Chrome 27.0 (Mac) slidebox directive "before each" hook FAILED
    Error: global leaks detected: setTimeout, setInterval, clearTimeout, clearInterval
```

Obviously, Sinon needs to do something to these globals to work its magic.  How can I tell Karma to ignore these particular globals?

**edit:**

This is for testing an [AngularJS directive that uses setInterval](https://github.com/keithjgrant/slidebox/).  If Angular provides another approach that is better/easier to test, I'm happy to use it instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll want to use $timeout in your directive. That will give you the ability to monitor it in your tests: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout

or if you need an interval, you may want to wrap your own service. See this issue : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2402 for a possible pattern.

Comment: I need an interval, not just a timeout...  I guess I can just explicitly re-set the timout at the end of each execution of my function?  Is there a better way?

Comment: for interval, you would need to restart and the end of every cycle. However, watch out for an issue in e2e tests:
/  
https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq
/  
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2402